# JS .map function is not displaying any element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `.map()` function on an array.

When I do a `console.log(object)` inside the .map it logs the object.
But when I do `<li key={key}>{object.name}</li>` it shows nothing.
Also not in the inspection tool.

Component:

```
<StyledImagesList>
    {this.state.images.map((imageObject, key) => {
        // <img src={imageObject.contentUrl} title={imageObject.name} />
        <li key={key}>{imageObject.name}</li>
        {console.log(imageObject)}
    })}
</StyledImagesList>
```

StyledImagesList has no styling

```
export const StyledImagesList = styled.ul;
```

Any idea why my `li` 's won't be visible?

Comment: you need to return something in a map

Comment: @JaromandaX but ofcourse... Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the `<li>` element in your `map()` callback should resolve the issue:

```
<StyledImagesList>
    { this.state.images.map((imageObject, key) => {
        // <img src={imageObject.contentUrl} title={imageObject.name} />

        /* Logging would need to happen before the return */
        console.log(imageObject);

        /* Add return here */
        return <li key={key}>{imageObject.name}</li>
    }) }
</StyledImagesList>
```

If logging to console were not needed, you could achieve the same result with the more concise equivalent of:

```
<StyledImagesList>
    { this.state.images.map((imageObject, key) => <li key={key}>{imageObject.name}</li>) }
</StyledImagesList>
```

Comment: There is a shortcut here for logging `=> console.log(imageObject) || <li key...` because the log is a Falsy return.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for that , this could come in handy 

Answer (score 2):

Return is missing. Either

```
    this.state.images.map((imageObject, key) => {
        return <li key={key}>{imageObject.name}</li>;
    })
```

or

```
    this.state.images.map((imageObject, key) => (
        <li key={key}>{imageObject.name}</li>
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Map()` uses `return` in it's code block in order to push each elements to a NEW array. It doesn't touch the original one.

The code you do inside the loop does run in fact... It's just that you didn't got any thing in return to show.

Doing

```
return <li key={key}>{imageObject.name}</li>
```

will build you a new array with those html elements for you.

> - The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element.
> - The map() method calls the provided function once for each element in an array, in order.
> - **Note:** map() does not execute the function for array elements without values.
> - **Note:** map() does not change the original array.